# Button not working in a fragment no errors?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

another newbie stuck with fragments/buttons!

I have a fragment with some spinners and a button the button should open a new activity but its does nothing - no errors or force close just nothing, any ideas??

thanks for the help :)

```
  package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class BreakfastFragment extends Fragment 


{

    private Button button;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_breakfast, container, false);


        String[] tables = { "Where are you?", "Take out", "Table 1", "Table 2",
                "Table 3", "Table 4", "Table 5", "Table 6", };
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.table_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> tableadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                tables);

        String[] bagels = { "Pick your Bagel!", "Plain", "Wholemeal", "Seeded", };
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_bageltype);
        ArrayAdapter<String> Bageladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                bagels);

        String[] fillings = { "A tasty filling?", "Bacon", "Sausage",
                "Bacon & Sausage", "Soft Cheese", "Butter" };
        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Filling);
        ArrayAdapter<String> fillingadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                fillings);

        String[] sauce = { "Any Sauce?", "Red", "Brown", "Mayo", "None", };
        Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sauce);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sauceadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sauce);

        tableadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        Bageladapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        fillingadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sauceadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(tableadapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(Bageladapter);
        spinner3.setAdapter(fillingadapter);
        spinner4.setAdapter(sauceadapter);

         return v;
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton(View v) {
        // Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want

         Button add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
            add.bringToFront();
            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Review.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;


                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Where you added `addListenerOnButton(v)` in `onCreateView(......)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add `addListenerOnButton(v)` in `Fragment onCreateView(......)` like:

```
 @Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View v = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_breakfast, container, false);

  addListenerOnButton(v);
  ...........
  ..........
 }
```

And Edit your `addListenerOnButton(v)` like a below:

```
public void addListenerOnButton(View v) {
     Button add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
     add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Review.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly thanks for the help been bugging me for ages just couldn't see it!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateView` add the following:

```
button = v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Review.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

And comment your `addListenerOnButton`